# How to add Nginx object caching for a CMS application (WordPress website)?

Tags: nginx, cache

I am having trouble applying object caching in Nginx, based on [this article](https://websiteforstudents.com/wordpress-fastcgi-caching-nginx-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/) (which I visited after failing to understand the official Nginx documentation on this).

I tried to add this to the very end of the `http{}` block in `nginx.conf`:

```
## Nginx FastCGI Cache
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=czone:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
    fastcgi_cache_lock on;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 60m;
    fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie:Set-Cookie;
    fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

After adding it I saved and executed `nginx -t` but I got an error "test failed".

The Nginx error log error gives this:

> mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/cache" failed (2: No such file or directory)`.

Seems that the the PHP `mkdir()` failed.

### My question

What are the correct POSIX directives for `/var/` so the PHP function could create `/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/` peacefully? What should be safe?

Or I shouldn't change `/var/`s POSIX directives and create `/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/` and change only its permissions, but to what?

Comment: You tell us why the test failed. We can't read it off your screen!

Comment: Comment by Thomas Ward: The proper answer is "You don't give any directives to PHP, you pre-create the directory yourself and then give whatever user PHP runs as read/write in the directory (or user/group ownership).

Comment: In my case, that user is `www-data`.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/907338/how-to-enable-nginx-object-caching

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed in comments, you have to pre create the directory for the nginx cache, likely under /var/cache/nginx and give correct permissions.

I usually use to

```
mkdir /var/cache/nginx
chmod 755 /var/cache/nginx
chown nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx
```

owner depends on your setup and distribution.

Nginx create the last directory, on my servers is chown nginx:nignx and chmod 700

Comment: it should be 700 writable by the nginx process. It should be www-data:www-data in your setup if nginx runs as www-data.

Comment: Just to clarify, the end dir I got is `/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/cache/` there seems to be a duplication. If I understand correct, I should delete this and start from scratch with the code you exampled.

Comment: Yes, it's not necessary but it would be simpler for you. I usually specify the app name. Example, not "cache" but "application_name".. like.. "mysite" and I end up with having /var/cache/nginx/mysite1 /var/cache/nginx/mysite2 depending on how many different caches you have